# Configuring multiple LAN domain names for Ubuntu server

Tags: samba, dns

I have a LAN with multiple PCs running Win 10 and one ubuntu server that is sharing 3 drives via samba. Each share can be accessed using own user and password. The question is how can map all the three network drives to a win 10 machine using 3 different usernames?

I read across google that you must apply different names to ubuntu server so that you can trick windows to believe there are different servers and that can be done in bind9.

I installed bind9 on the ubuntu server and now i need to configure it but i really don't know how.

The configuration will be like this:

1. drive x with username x-user and x-pass shared as like from x-local domanin
2. drive y with username y-user and y-pass shared as like from y-local domanin
3. drive z with username z-user and z-pass shared as like from z-local domanin

All the shares will point to the same ip address (192.168.0.10 - the server ip) but different domanin names.

How can i configure bind9 so when i call x-local, y-local and z-local from my lan will point to 192.168.0.10?

The samba configuration is already done...

Thanks!